# For given $t$ and $x$ and $y$, is there at least one $f$ such that $\cos ft = x, \sin ft =y$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, trigonometry, inverse

Suppose that $t$, $x$ and $y$ are given and are all in $\mathbb{R}$. Is there always at least one $f$ such that $\cos ft = x, \sin ft =y$?

Edit: OK I forgot to add that given $x$ and $y$ are such that $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and $t \neq 0$ and $t>0$.

Comment: Certainly not, since if $\cos(ft)=x$, then $\cos^2(ft)=x^2$ so $1-\sin^2(ft)=x^2=1-y^2$.

Comment: this is true for any real $f$

Comment: The parameter $t$ is irrelevant. Assume there is a solution $f$ for some $t$, then for any $t'$, $f'=ft/t'$ is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

As$$\sin^2(ft)+\cos^2(ft)=1$$ is true whatever the argument, any $f$ is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The measure of the angle in the centre (in radians) is $cos^{-1}(x)$. So $f=cos^{-1}(x)/t$ will work.